# Django ModelAdmin get queryset from ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

Im Using a ModelForm for creating a form from a model for using in various places on my site. The form has a Foreign Key field which needs to be filtered based on the user. I have successfully done this using:

```
class TestForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self,user,*args,**kwargs):
        super (TestForm,self ).__init__(*args,**kwargs) # populates the post
        self.fields['controller'].queryset = Controller.objects.filter(user=user)

    class Meta:
        model = Test
        exclude = ['customer']
```

And then in my view using: `form = TestForm(user)`

This is working fine for my forms outside of Django Admin, but my site requires that the model be editable inside Django Admin aswell. So I used this code for my ModelAdmin, based on the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_form)

```
class TestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            kwargs['form'] = SuTestForm
        else:
            kwargs['form'] = TestForm(request.user)
        return super(TestAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

I would think this should work just as is does for my other forms but i am getting this error back from django: `invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'TestForm'`

After a bit of googeling i came across this approach which puts the queryset filtering inside the ModelAdmin:

```
form = super(TestAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
form.base_fields['controller_fk'].queryset = Controller.objects.filter(custid=cust)
return form
```

This works perfectly fine but it does require me to create multiple copies of my ModelForm which doesn't seem very dry. So i guess does anyone know how to get my ModelForm queryset returned into the ModelAdmin form?

Comment: I'm not really sure what's the problem (you haven't provided a full stacktrace to see where the querying goes bad) however could you try returning your form instance directly from the ``get_form`` method and see what happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble is that you are actually instantiating your form in the else clause, whereas the other clause returns the class rather than an instance. Both branches need to return a class.

Unfortunately, there's no easy hook in the ModelAdmin class to provide extra kwargs for a form instantiation: it takes place deep inside the `changeform_view` method which is much harder to override than it should be. You would need to do something clever to return a class with the user value baked in from get_form.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I thought I'd offer an alternative for future searches.

You can use a *factory function* which will capture the `HttpRequest` object for use in  `TestForm`, then return the `TestForm` class back to the calling function (in this case, `get_form()`. This way you can access the current `request.user` object in `TestForm` and filter accordingly:

*forms.py*

```
def _test_form_factory(request):
""" Capture request object for use in TestForm, then return the TestForm class. """

    class TestForm(ModelForm):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
            if request.user.is_superuser:
                return
            self.fields['controller'].queryset = Controller.objects.filter(user=request.user)

        class Meta:
            model = Test
            exclude = ['customer']

    return TestForm
```

*admin.py*

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    """ Capture request object for use in the form. """
    self.form = _test_form_factory(request)
    return super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

*NOTE:* All code logic can be performed in `TestForm` -- no need for `SuTestForm`, assuming all it did was pass back the full queryset for the `controller` form field in it. Even if `SuTestForm` performs other logic specific to the class, you should find that you can migrate the code to `TestForm` now, since you have access to the `HttpRequest` object.